# Get n most recent records in a foreign key's table (Rails ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, model

Simple question here.

I have a User table. Each User has many Goals. Each Goal has many Objectives. Each Objective has a `created_at` column.

I'd like to get the 10 most recent Objectives created for a User (regardless of any specific Goal), but I'm not sure how to structure the ActiveRecord query.

I know how to get the 10 most recent Objectives in general. You would do the following:

```
Objective.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => 'created_at desc')
```

But I don't know how to get the 10 most recent Objectives for a specific User (i.e. going from User -> Goal -> Objective).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `has_many :through`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :goals
  has_many :objectives, :through => :goals
end
```

Now, whenever you do `user.objectives` you'll get all objectives of the user regardless of the goal.

So in order to get the latest objectives :

```
user = User.find(your_id)
latest_objectives = user.objectives.order('created_at desc').limit(10)
```

Comment: Thanks. `goals` needs a colon next to it, though. :)